# How to mock exception for junit coverage?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a class that cause exception. What I want is to mock that exception but with the coverage (so spy is needed) how do I mock with mockito so that Junit coverage will able to count those exception as covered?

For example:

```
    private List<Data> _getSomeData(Key key) {
        log.debug(logPrefix + " GetSomeData");
        Connection dbc = null;
        PreparedStatement st = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String q = null;
        ....
        try {
            dbc = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource);
            dbc.setAutoCommit(false);
            q = "SELECT value FROM table where x = ? and y = ? and z = ?";      

            st = dbc.prepareStatement(q);
            int ix = 1;
            st.setInt(ix++, key.x);
            st.setInt(ix++, key.y);
            st.setInt(ix++, key.z);
            rs = st.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Data data=new Data();
                key.id = rs.getLong("x");
                key.y = y;
                ....
                DataList.add(data);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DbException(e, q);
        } finally {
            DbUtil.cleanup(log, rs, st, dbc);
        }
    return  dataList;
    }
```

So from above what I want is to cover the exception. How do I cover it with the coverage?

Jutest ->

```
    @Test
    public void testException(){
//      DataImpl dataDao = new DataImpl();
//      dataDao.setLog(new LogImpl());
        DataImpl dataDao = Mockito.spy(new DataImpl()); 
        Key key= new Key();
        key.x = 1;
        key.y = 1;
        key.z = 1;
        String q = 
        " SELECT data.* \n" +
        " FROM SOME_DATA d1\n" +
        " WHERE\n "+
        " d1.x = ? \n " +
        " AND ROUND (d1.y/ 1000 - 1) = ? \n" +
        " AND MOD (d1.z, 1000) = ?";
        Mockito.doThrow(new DbException(null, q)).when(invPPNDataDao)._getSomeData(Key);
    }
```

Above will work but it will not be covered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do here is a dependency injection. Then you can mock it and define how it will behave. Currently, you are constructing a lot of objects in your method (`DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource)`, `new Data()`, ...)  which are hardly testable.

You can create class `DbcProvider`:

```
public class DbcProvider {

    public Connection newDbc() {
        DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource);
    }

}
```

Then in your test you mock `DbcProvider` and set it to throw exception when `newDbc` is called, and then you call your method `_getSomeData`.